# How to do transaction.insert_or_update on secondary index and not the primary index?

Tags: database, indexing, key, ddl, google-cloud-spanner

I have a table in Google Cloud Spanner.

```
CREATE TABLE test_id (
    Id STRING(MAX) NOT NULL,
    KeyColumn STRING(MAX) NOT NULL,
    parent_id INT64 NOT NULL,
    Updated TIMESTAMP NOT NULL OPTIONS (allow_commit_timestamp=true),
) PRIMARY KEY (Id)
```

And, I am trying to perform `transaction.insert_or_update` through a python script.
For each row in a pandas dataframe, I am doing:

```
transaction.insert_or_update(
                'test_id', columns=['Id','KeyColumn', 'parent_id', 'Updated'],
                values=[(uuid.uuid4().hex, row["KeyColumn"], row["parent_id"], spanner.COMMIT_TIMESTAMP)],
            )
```

What I want is that if the row["KeyColumn"] is already present in `KeyColumn` of the table, update its `parent_id` column, otherwise insert a new row in the Spanner table corresponding to that KeyColumn. 
But since, my primary key is `Id` which is generated randomly by `uuid.uuid4().hex`, it every time inserts a new row.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, the following is the situation:

- `ID` is the primary key of your table.
- There is a unique index defined for the table on the column `KeyColumn`.
- You want to `insert_or_update` a row using `KeyColumn` as the column that should be used to determine whether the row already exists.

That is unfortunately not possible. `insert_or_update` will always use the primary key of the table to determine whether the row exists. I can think of three possible solutions to this problem, but they all have their drawbacks:

- You could change the table definition and make `KeyColumn` the primary key and set a unique index on the `Id` column. The problem with this is of course that any other code that depends on `Id` being the primary key also needs to change. It is also a rather cumbersome change, because Cloud Spanner does not allow you to change the primary key of a table, so you would have to create a copy of the `test_id` table and then drop the old table.
- You could fetch the row from Cloud Spanner before updating it by reading it using the `KeyColumn` value that you have. The big problem with this is obviously performance. You will need to do a read for each row that you want to update.
- You could use a DML statement (`UPDATE test_id SET parent_id=@parent WHERE KeyColumn=@key`) to execute the update and check whether it actually updated a row by checking the returned update count. If it did not update anything, you could then execute the insert. This will obviously also be slower than an `insert_or_update` mutation.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/secondary-indexes#query-with-index) there is a way to query the Cloud Spanner with a specific index.
You should use something like this in the end of your query : `FROM test_id@{FORCE_INDEX=KeyColumnIndex}` .

Even though this is the way to execute queries on secondary indexes and the answer for the question in the title, I do not know how much it can be applied in your use case.